# Rows into Columns by using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

Can you help me to solve this error

> The type of column "nvrchildgender" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHRIS_ChildDetails](
    [intCHID] [int],
    [intSID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nvrChildname] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [nvrChildGender] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [dttChildDOB] [datetime] NULL,
    [nvrnominee] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [nvrChildOccupation] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [dttCreatedon] [datetime] NULL,
    [dttModifiedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [nvrModifiedby] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Query:

```
select *
from
(
  select value, col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col
  from
  (
    select nvrchildname,
      nvrchildgender,
      convert(nvarchar(10), dttchildDOB, 120) dttchildDOB,
      nvrchildoccupation,
      row_number() over(partition by intsid order by intCHID) rn
    from tblHRIS_ChildDetails
    where intsid = 463
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value 
    for col in (nvrchildname, nvrchildgender, dttchildDOB,  nvrchildoccupation)
  ) unpiv
) src1
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([nvrchildname_1], [nvrgender_1], 
              [dttchildDOB_1], [occupation_1], 
              [nvrchildname_2], [nvrgender_2], 
              [dttchildDOB_2], [occupation_2]) 
) piv
```

I cannot to able to run this query i think some cast problem pls resolve.

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84775/1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [rows into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599404/rows-into-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To UNPIVOT successfully, the column types must match. Since two of the 4 columns are already `nvarchar(250)` and the other two shorter, promoting them to `nvarchar(250)` is the most expedient fix.

```
select *
from
(
  select value, col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col
  from
  (
    select nvrchildname,
      cast(nvrchildgender as nvarchar(250)) nvrgender,
      convert(nvarchar(250), dttchildDOB, 120) dttchildDOB,
      nvrchildoccupation occupation,
      row_number() over(partition by intsid order by intCHID) rn
    from tblHRIS_ChildDetails
    where intsid = 463
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value 
    for col in (nvrchildname, nvrgender, dttchildDOB, occupation)
  ) unpiv
) src1
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([nvrchildname_1], [nvrgender_1], 
              [dttchildDOB_1], [occupation_1], 
              [nvrchildname_2], [nvrgender_2], 
              [dttchildDOB_2], [occupation_2]) 
) piv
```

**Note:** You have named the PIVOT column `nvrgender` but the base column was `nvrchildgender`. Same problem with mismatched `occupation` column naming between pivot and unpivot.

Comment: Hi if u run this select nvrchildname,
      cast(nvrchildgender as nvarchar(250)) nvrchildgender,
      convert(nvarchar(250), dttchildDOB, 120) dttchildDOB,
      nvrchildoccupation,
      row_number() over(partition by intsid order by intCHID) rn
    from tblHRIS_ChildDetails
    where intsid = 463 you will get gender and occupation but it is not returning in the form

Answer (score 0):

The columns in the `UNPIVOT` list:

```
nvrchildname, nvrchildgender, dttchildDOB,  nvrchildoccupation
```

Have different data types.

You have to ensure that the types of the columns. Something like :

```
 ...
  CAST(nvrchildname AS NVARCHAR(10)) nvrchildname,
  CAST(nvrchildgender AS NVARCHAR(10)) nvrchildgender,
  convert(nvarchar(10), dttchildDOB, 120) dttchildDOB,
  CAST (nvrchildoccupation AS NVARCHAR(10)) nvrchildoccupation
 ...
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84775/9)

Comment: @mahmound where gender there but it returns null check it

Comment: Check gender and childocupation is missing

Comment: Hi if u run this select nvrchildname, cast(nvrchildgender as nvarchar(250)) nvrchildgender, convert(nvarchar(250), dttchildDOB, 120) dttchildDOB, nvrchildoccupation, row_number() over(partition by intsid order by intCHID) rn from tblHRIS_ChildDetails where intsid = 463 you will get gender and occupation but it is not returning in the Fiddle did u check that